# How can i do npm module support import and require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I uploaded my first module to npm in Javascript and I want it to support import and require. Is this possible?

The module is this:
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dariodigulio/pro-log-js**

Comment: my module was wrote with module sintax. But, when i'm try import with require, in consolo print this error
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025
  throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename);
  ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\Desktop\test-pro-

Comment: From my limited experience, you can `import` a commonjs module - but you can't `require` an ESM module - so, in the one case where I needed both - I wrote the code as commonjs, and provided an export ESM module file that imports the commonjs and exports it - of course, if you really wanted to stick with ESM syntax, you could write ESM, and then use some sort of "transpiler" to convert it to commonjs and publish that ...

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/aelbore/65a4d2e86c3326f36607db111a7b6887  You create 2 folders for require & import. the package.json part: "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require":  "./cjs/my-lib.js",
      "default": "./esm/my-lib.js"
    }
  },

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I get the same error when I did try to `require()` your package. But, then I manged to get both working (`import...from` and `require()`) by converting your package code to `commonjs` compatible.

You should try to publish the package as `commonjs` (`require()`) module and then you'll [get support](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) from Node to choose either syntax on application side.

I did following change in your code to get both syntax working.

1. Removed the `"type": "module"` from `package.json`.
2. Update the `main` entry from "main": "ProLog.mjs", to `"main": "ProLog.js"`.
3. Replace the `import...from` syntax with `require()` in `ProLog.js` file.
4. Update the `export class ProLog` to `module.exports = ProLog`.